# Why is this C# SQL Login system not working?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I'm not getting an actual error but its returning false every time:

```
string commandString = 
    "SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Username = @UserName";
DataTable result = new DataTable();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandString, dataConnection))
{

    command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.username;
    using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        result.Load(dr);
    }
}
if (result.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Rows[0]["Password"]);
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Rows[0]["Username"]);
    Console.WriteLine(info.password);
    Console.WriteLine(info.username);
    string dbPassword = (string)result.Rows[0]["Password"];
    if (string.Compare(dbPassword, info.password) == 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
else
    return false;
```

Comment: "not working" is, no matter wether you have trouble with your car or with a piece of code, a rather bad way to ask for help.

Comment: First question would be... What error do you get?

Comment: Where is it going wrong or what is exactly going wrong?

Comment: Never mind the fact that you're storing passwords in plaintext, and pulling them up from the database to make your compare... Have you tried debugging, and seeing what your query returns?

Comment: sorry i realized that i didn't post up the problem when i hit submit and was in the process of editing my post when all y'all commented

Comment: Use debugger, put a break point on string dbPassword and see what are you getting, also check info.password

Comment: All of the above, plus where does the `info` object come from?

Comment: yes im just testing my database right now thats why its plain text, and its not returning anything right now its rows.count is always 0

Comment: info is a message object from the client just holds username and password for right now

Comment: @Shredder2500 - You do understand you have a huge bug in your code right?  You really should not try to create your own username/password system if your unable to write clearn SQL code.  Use the default ASP.NET Provider, much better, and doesn't have a glaring SQL Injection bug.

Comment: Isn't using a DataTable overkill?

Comment: @mouters im going to be returning more data with it in the future

Comment: @Ramhound Well im trying to learn so if you can point out the bug that would be great

Comment: @Shredder2500, I am not sure if this will solve your problem but try a dataadapter, something like. `SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
myAdapter.Fill(result);` instead of `using (SqlDataReader dr ...`

Comment: @Shredder2500 - There are to many to list in a comment.

Comment: are you sure that your password is same in info and dbpassword
means not case sensitive issue

Comment: yes im sure i just did a console.writeline on both the dbpassword and info.password both the same. also did the same with the username

Comment: @Ramhound could you send me a link to where i can learn then?

Comment: did you debug your code? what happened at if condition.

Comment: @Shoaib Muhammad Khan yes I have added more console.writelines to see what is being received from the database and it all looks correct and I also did that for the login info and that also looks correct so im not sure why its not working

Comment: just updated my post to show the debuging console.writelines

Comment: change your if condition to if(dpassword.tolower().equals(info.password.tolower()))
then see the results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14064/discussion-between-shredder2500-and-shoaib-muhammad-khan)

Comment: @Shredder2500 - No, do your own research, and use the ASP.NET Provider that does exactly this.  There is no reason you can't use it within a desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in condition.

```
dbPassword.ToLower().trim() == info.password.ToLower().trim()
```

Answer (score 7):

Think I see the problem

```
if (result.Rows.Count == 0)
```

Needs to be

```
if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
```

Otherwise your checking if you have 0 rows instead of 1 row and then you can check the result on row 0 where the data is in

Comment: Certainly one of the problems. =)

Comment: yes this was a problem lol dont know why i did that, ok so now its getting past that part but still returning false

Comment: @Shredder2500 - I suggest you say the username is `*` and in order to understand how poor this code really is.

Comment: If a user has more than one matching record this will fail too.

Comment: i did greater than 0 but im not going to let there be more that one username